# Cannot find a way to replace last row inside excel files

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I am fighting with an excel file in which I would simple delete the last row.
I am using XLSXWRITER, and I tried several ways, but nothing is working. I am doing something wrong (maybe I have to take a break).

I tried

```
worksheet.write_blank(row, col, None)
```

but I found out that xlsxwriter cannot replace an old row with a new one. So if I use `write_blank()` to write on on an existing row, it won't work.

Could you please help me? I am looping through several XLSX file, open them and replace the last row with a blank.

Many thanks!

Comment: Well, have you tried reading in the entire content of the xlsx file into a variable, modifying the content of the variable to remove the last row, deleting the existing xlsx file and creating it anew with the contents from the variable?
If the module can't rewrite and existing line of the file, this seems to me to be the only option left. While I agree that it is probably not very efficient to create a whole new file just to remove one line, if the module doesn't give you any other choice then that is what you'll need to do!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I found a way out using different library. I'll keep in mind your suggest for future needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a way to achieve this step on my own.
Basically I wasn't able to do this with XLSXWRITER library, so I loop through my excel files opening them with OPENPYXL.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

## look for all excel files needed
filepath = r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\folder\folder\folder"
xlsxfiles = glob.glob(filepath + r"\**\*.xlsx")

## for each excel file open the workbook and spreadsheet
for file in xlsxfiles:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    ws = wb.active
    ## for each excel file, count the maximum number of rows and store the value in last_row variable
    last_row = ws.max_row
    print("MAX NUMER OF ROW: ", last_row)
    ## replace the last row with None value
    ws.cell(last_row, 1).value = None
    ## save each excel file
    wb.save(file)
```

My need was quite specific but I think it can be easily modify to different purposes.